# Writing XY coordinates from an ASCII file with no feature part ID using Python

Tags: python, ascii, arcgis

I need to read an ASCII file containing X and Y coordinates as well a Z value using Python. These will be written as features in a feature class in ArcMap. Each point makes up a polygon where each feature is seperated by a row containing '999.0 999.0 999.0' as shown in the example. I'm wondering what the best way is to seperate each feature as there is no feature ID column.

```
329462.713287 8981177.910780 0.000000
331660.441771 8981187.405700 0.000000
331669.945462 8978975.695090 0.000000
329472.340912 8978966.180280 0.000000
329462.713287 8981177.910780 0.000000
999.0 999.0 999.0
297517.590475 8981318.596530 0.000000
299715.649732 8981329.876880 0.000000
299726.953175 8979117.630860 0.000000
297529.017922 8979106.326860 0.000000
297517.590475 8981318.596530 0.000000
999.0 999.0 999.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate the data line by line, and check whether the line contains your *magic* triplet and when you catch that line increase the feature index.